# How can I make two array in data vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I try like this :

```
<template>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        data() {
            return {
                tabs: [
                    {
                        sale:{
                            {
                                url: 'store/sale',
                                group: 'index'
                            },
                            {
                                url: 'store/confirm',
                                group: 'confirm'
                            },
                        },
                        purchase:{
                            {
                                url: '/profile/purchase',
                                group: 'payment'
                            },
                            {
                                url: '/profile/purchase/order',
                                group: 'order'
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If the code executed, there exist error :

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

It seems the error occurred in the data

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a syntax error:

```
sale:{
      {
        url: 'store/sale',
        group: 'index'
      },
      {
        url: 'store/confirm',
        group: 'confirm'
      },
     }
```

Same with `purchase:{{})`

I suspect you want those to be arrays (made with `[ ]`) not objects (with `{ }`). Maybe this is what you are trying to do:

```
sale:[
      {
        url: 'store/sale',
        group: 'index'
      },
      {
        url: 'store/confirm',
        group: 'confirm'
      },
     ],
purchases[{
  // etc.
     }
    ]
```